# WooCommerce Hook To Check Number Of Checkout Form Validation Errors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run an API call on woocommerce checkout once the checkout form has been completely validated.

Is there a woocommerce function that will return the amount of errors in the form? Or a hook that I can use once the form is validated but the order not placed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The correct hooks to be used are included in [`WC_Checkout` `process_checkout()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#940-995)

Comment: I also need to set the order number in woocommerce on creation as we need it to relate to a field in our ERP.

Is there anyway I can set this using a hook or function? 

Matt

Comment: Just think about it *(explanations are just too broad)*  The order Id is generated from the next available post ID (as Orders are a custom post type "shop_order"… Your ERP will never be able to **set the order ID in WC_Checkout process**. You can only get it. Your ERP need to be adapted to woocommerce generated Ids and not the contrary. What you can do is create a custom field that will be a kind of ERP order ID…